# Printing Python output with subprocess.run and emailing it out

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to print out Python output and emailing but it is getting stuck when I call the subprocess.run() function. I am not sure what the issue is.

run_email function:

```
@staticmethod
def run_email(log_filename, sender_email, sender_password, receiver_email):
    log_mod.setup_logging(log_filename)

    # Run your script as a subprocess and capture its output
    command = [sys.executable,
                "C:\\Users\\digital\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\data\\downloads\\local_loadscript.py"]
    completed_process = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True)
    print(completed_process.stdout)
    captured_output = completed_process.stdout
    print(captured_output)
    log_mod.log("Captured script output:\n" + captured_output)

    # Send email with log content
    with open(log_filename, 'r') as log_file:
        log_content = log_file.read()
        print(log_content)
    log_mod.send_email(log_filename, log_content, sender_email, sender_password, receiver_email)
```

This is how Im calling it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
obj = LocalStorage()
obj.my_list_bucket(base_folder, current_day)  # execute code
obj.run_email("Data Loading Log for {}".format(current_day), sender_email, sender_password, receiver_email)
```

I made some changes but it is looping for some reason:
Changed:

```
completed_process = subprocess.run(command,capture_output=True, text=True)
```

To:

```
completed_process = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This is the output, it keeps looping the futurewarning message:

C:\Users\digital\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data\downloads\local_loadscript.py:312:   FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
bdf.columns = bdf.columns.str.strip().str.replace('.', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.lower()

C:\Users\digital\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data\downloads\local_loadscript.py:312: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
bdf.columns = bdf.columns.str.strip().str.replace('.', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.lower()

C:\Users\digital\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data\downloads\local_loadscript.py:312: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
bdf.columns = bdf.columns.str.strip().str.replace('.', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.lower()

Loaded 2380 rows and 15 columns to analyticsdata-222222.emaildownloads.adara_20230905

Loaded 6 rows and 12 columns to analyticsdata-222222.downloads.adarasummary_20230905

Data Loading Log for 20230905
C:\Users\digital\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data\downloads\local_loadscript.py:312: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
bdf.columns = bdf.columns.str.strip().str.replace('.', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.lower()

C:\Users\digital\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data\downloads\local_loadscript.py:312: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
bdf.columns = bdf.columns.str.strip().str.replace('.', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.lower()

C:\Users\digital\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data\downloads\local_loadscript.py:312: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
bdf.columns = bdf.columns.str.strip().str.replace('.', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.lower()

C:\Users\digital\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data\downloads\local_loadscript.py:312: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
bdf.columns = bdf.columns.str.strip().str.replace('.', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.lower()

C:\Users\digital\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data\downloads\local_loadscript.py:312: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
bdf.columns = bdf.columns.str.strip().str.replace('.', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.lower()

C:\Users\digital\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\data\downloads\local_loadscript.py:312: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
bdf.columns = bdf.columns.str.strip().str.replace('.', '').str.replace(' ', '').str.lower()

Comment: Sounds like your `local_loadscript.py` script is getting stuck, then. What does it do?

Comment: Why do you run a python script via subprocess from another python script ? Can't you just import it ?

Comment: It loads files from the download folder into Bigquery, if I dont call the obj.run_email() in the main it completes the script. @AKX

Comment: What happens if you run `C:\\Users\\digital\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\data\\downloads\\local_loadscript.py` from a terminal? does it complete succesfully?

Comment: Wdym by importing? You can import a python output to email? I saw online that if you wanted to capture the python output you have to use subprocess.run. @Itération122442

Comment: Yes, if I run path to the file in terminal it completes successfully. @MatteoZanoni

Comment: You could just encapsulate the instructions of `local_loadscript.py` into a function which would return the output you expect and then import that script and call that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, instead of using subprocess.run to get the output, I used sys.stdout.

```
output_file_path = "output.txt"  # Define the path for capturing output

# Redirect stdout to a file
with open(output_file_path, "w") as file:
    sys.stdout = file

    # Call the function or block of code to capture its output
    

# Restore stdout to the original value (typically the console)
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

# Optionally, you can read and print the captured output from the file
with open(output_file_path, "r") as file:
    captured_output = file.read()
    print("Captured Output:")
    print(captured_output)

# Send the captured output as an email
subject = "Captured Output for {}".format(current_day)
body = "Please find the attached captured output."
log_mod.send_email(subject, body, output_file_path, "sender_email@gmail.com", "sender_password", "receiver_email@gmail.com")
```